# How to extend project properties page?

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2008, vsx, extensibility

Is it possible to add a custom tab to a project properties page in the Visual Studio 2008?
What I want to do is to be able to add a custom tab to properties page for the projects created from default project templates (WPF Application, WPF custom controls library, etc).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Keith,

I'm working on VS add-in for WPF applications localization. I want to be able to manage project specific settings via "project properties" page. I did some research and it seems that it is not possible to extend existing projects in this way.

Answer (score 0):

It seems that during the time this question was asked, this feature was not implemented in Visual Studio SDK.

There's answer for similar question https://stackoverflow.com/a/5325158/2617201 which refers to Microsoft Documentation at [Adding and Removing Property Pages](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/extensibility/adding-and-removing-property-pages?view=vs-2015&redirectedfrom=MSDN). The article refers to Visual Studio 2015 (later versions should have the same feature).